# "apt upgrade" returns "Errors were encountered while processing" for linux-image and initramfs-tools

Tags: linux, debian, initramfs

I recently installed debian 12 stable and when I do `apt upgrade`, I get error with linux-image and below is the complete traceback. What's causing it and how do I not get this error message anymore?

```
naveen@debian12:~$ sudo apt upgrade -y 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64 (6.1.38-2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.0-10-amd64.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.1.0-10-amd64.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-10-amd64
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64 (= 6.1.38-2); however:
  Package linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-10-amd64
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and here are my sources

```
naveen@debian12:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free-firmware

# bookworm-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free-firmware
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have installed the `raspi-firmware` package, which includes the firmware and bootloaders required by the Raspberry Pi series of ARM-based single-board computers. Yet your kernel has a `-amd64` suffix, suggesting that the system is a regular 64-bit x86 system.

Apparently the `raspi-firmware` package includes some script that takes part in initramfs creation, and it is erroring out - probably because the system does not have an ARM processor.

Comment: I did `sudo apt purge raspi-firmware` and rebooted my computer. I still get `errors were encountered` with `apt upgrade`:
```
 linux-image-6.1.0-11-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
 linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```